# Marquee TextView alpha property is not working

Tags: android

I want to make background of a marquee text view completely non transparent, and for this i set the android alpha property 1 in my xml file. But it is not working. It is still transparent Please help.
android:background="#A0A0A0"
android:alpha = "1"

[image]

Comment: Apply a non transparent colour and check. I think that will work for you. Like set the background colour to #00A0A0A0, remove the alpha property and then check. :)

Comment: It's not working.In this case there is transparent background.So they still overlapping

Comment: Is there any way to setting background completely non transparent

Comment: Ok sorry Manoj. I actually given you the wrong value. My mistake. Instead of initial 00 try FF and then let me know

Comment: All right Abhishek. I tried it But it is not working in my case:(

Comment: Is it still overlapping  ??

Comment: yes still overlapping because background is still not completely non trasparent

Comment: Hey Manoj, I've put two textview one over another and gave marquee to the Foreground textview and gave your background colour with the alpha and it seems to be working fine. Please check your code if you are doing something wrong or not ? If you want, I can share screenshots with you. :)

Comment: yes please Abhishek it would be helpfull for me if you provide the screen shot.Thnnxx:)

Comment: Please check here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m62n91x0aue4h1i/AABIttrZyImMgbZoOLSlgNiEa?dl=0

Comment: where alpha in float like 1f, 1.5f etc...?

Comment: No i am giving integer value 1 only